# Add a finacing value to product page opencart

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I am trying to create a simple finance calculator that will show under the price on the product page.

Here is the simplest version of the code I have tried.

```
<?php $price * .265; ?>
```

Every way I go about it I get a result of 0 unless I just print the price itself.

I have tried making the price a separate variable and did a few integer conversions.

I am not a super skilled programmer but this seems like it should be simple enough to accomplish. Is there something I need to add to the controller file?

Comment: Have you tried a space after `$price`?  or you could try putting `$price` in a set of parenthesis.  `<?php print(($price) * 0.265); ?>`

Comment: Yes I tried adding parenthesis and a few other syntax variations same result

Comment: Does $price print okay?

Comment: I have a math question back: What is `x` multiplied with zero? E.g. what is `0 * 0.265` for example?

Comment: Yes $price alone prints fine.

Comment: That's odd... how about `echo` instead of `print`?  Also can you try taking away the leading 0?  ` * .265`

Comment: echo is giving same result as print and I have tried in with and without the leading zero

Comment: Try this... `<?php $financeprice = ($price * 0.265); 
echo $financeprice;
?>`

Comment: first thing I tried, I'm looking at converting the variable to an integer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll I solved the issue

```
$int = filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$finance = $int/100*.2655/36;
echo round($finance);
```

This allows me to do algebraic calculations with the price on the product page and give estimate on monthly financing.